# Firebase Hosting: Caching the underlying file from a re-written route

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

**Problem**:

Unable to apply caching headers to re-written routes (i.e. /bla -> /index.html).

Firebase documentation clearly states that the headers are applied when the 'source' glob pattern matches the original request.

Can anyone help with a workaround / solution to this?

**Code**:

Note: The headers directive for the 'index.html' source does not work unless the user directly hits /index.html, but is kept in the code to better articulate the issue.

```
{
  "database": {
    "rules": "database.rules.json"
  },
  "hosting": {
    "public": "build",
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source" : "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ],
    "headers": [
      {
        "source": "index.html",
        "headers": [
          {
            "key" : "Cache-Control",
            "value" : "max-age=0"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "source": "**/*.@(js|css)",
        "headers": [
          {
            "key" : "Cache-Control",
            "value" : "max-age=31536000"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```